# "in" or "to" a theorem?

Tags: sentence-construction

Should I use "in" or "to" in this sentence?

> Theorem 1 plays an important rule in the proof of Theorem 2, and hence
>   the weighted version of it will be very important `"in"` Theorem 3.

Also, is this sentence correct?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by "weighted version"?

Comment: @shin I edited my post a little bit. by "weighted version", I mean some certain modification of Theorem 1.

Comment: so you want to say that theorem 1 is important in proving theorem 3?

Comment: @shin Yes, the weighted version of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will construct it this way: "Theorem 1 is an important rule [theorem] in proving Theorem 2; hence, the weighted version of the former [Theorem 1] is essential/important in proving Theorem 3."